# Regex in LIKE Clause that accepts only Alphanumeric and dashes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Below is my SQL function script that will help identify the alphanumeric value and dashes (`-`):

```sql
CREATE   FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_VALIDATE_ALPHANUMERIC_AND_DASHES](@TX_INPUT VARCHAR(1000))RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN     
    DECLARE @bitInputVal AS BIT = 0
    DECLARE @InputText VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @InputText = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@TX_INPUT,'')))
  
    IF @InputText <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @bitInputVal = CASE
                                WHEN @InputText LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9-]%' THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
    END
  RETURN @bitInputVal
END
```

I have problem which I try this query:
`SELECT dbo.FN_VALIDATE_CLAIMANT_REF_NO('AbcdefgH-1234*')` it gives me a result of `1` though the character `*` is not included in the regex and should return `0` instead.

What I want to achieve is to explicitly verify if the string consist of **alphanumeric** *(alphabets and numbers)* and **dashes** only.

Please note that there are no limitation in length of the characters, only check if the string consist of alphanumeric and dashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing for "whether any alphabet, number or dash is present in the string"

You should instead test whether *any character other than* alphabet, number or dash is present.

```
SET @bitInputVal = CASE WHEN @InputText LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9-]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Yes you're correct and this is what I am looking for :) thanks for the answer. I just missed a little tiny detail.